# create custom triggers google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

How to create a custom run trigger to execute a function to run alternate Mondays at 6 pm.

```js
function createCustomTrigger() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('myFunction')
      .timeBased()
      .onWeekDay(ScriptApp.WeekDay.MONDAY)
      .atHour(6)
      .create();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`everyWeeks()` method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder#everyWeeks(Integer)).

```
ScriptApp.newTrigger('myFunction')
    .timeBased()
    .everyWeeks(2)
    .onWeekDay(ScriptApp.Weekday.MONDAY)
    .atHour(6)
    .create();
```